# Не могу корректно настроить VS Code для C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

Поставил VS Code для работы с C# и на данный момент, при запуске самой простой программы, VS Code сообщает, что нет инструментов для отладки C#. В Marketplace установил C# Tools for Godot,  но результат тот же. Подскажите, как правильно все настроить все под C#?

Comment: При чем тут c# и Godot? VS Code поддерживает только .NET Core и выше, у вас надеюсь этот тип проекта?

Comment: Вряд ли, я очень слабо разобрался в этом. Можете подсказать?

Comment: Я разобрался с подключение типа проекта, но все равно та же ситуация

Comment: Что подсказать? Какая "та же ситуация"? Вот представьте, что вы выбежали на улицу, поймали первого попавшегося мужика/бабку и вот вы должны ему, человеку, который совершенно не представляет, что у вас в голове, доходчиво объяснить суть вашей проблемы, чтобы тот мог хотяб начать думать в нужном направление. Вот я первый попавшийся мужик с улицы, вы мне "VS Code", "C#", "нет инструментов для отладки", "Godot". Я вам говорю "Ну так проект должен быть `.NET Core` и при чем тут `Godot`"? А вы в ответ мне "я плохо разбираюсь, помогите." И вот как бы в голове "с чем", "что этот человек сделал?"

Comment: Вот давайте, разбирайтесь что у вас там за проект, если это `.NET Framework`, то VS Code не для вас. Если .`.NET Core`, то проблем с запуском у вас быть не должно, достаточно установить одно расширение, которое зовется просто `C#`, и да, его должна предложить сама VS Code... Вы установили его?

Comment: Все уже установленно, как и .Net Core. Дело лишь в том, что я просто не создал проект через консоль (dotnet new console), поэтому ничего и не работало